# What to do about [labeling] and [classification] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed an overlap of subjects between tags [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) (x1185) and [classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification) (x363), in which the concept of the former is contained in the latter (see questions within GIS SE and tag excerpts).

Currently, their excerpt says:

> [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling):
> Annotating data on a map using text and/or graphics.
>
> [classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification):
> The process of sorting or arranging entities into groups or categories; on a map, the process of representing members of a group by the same symbol, usually defined in a legend.

The problem with this is that people searching about representing data on a map will find content split across such tags.

Do you think something should be done? If yes, what? Or are we just fine?

Comment: Typically, when I think of classification with respect to GIS, I think of image classification. Perhaps we need a tag specifically for image classification to avoid confusion. It seems many of the classification posts relate to image classification.

Comment: There is also point cloud classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not expect to see [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) as a concept within [classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification).

I think the problem is that the tag wiki excerpt for [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) has been set as:

> Annotating data on a map using text and/or graphics.

rather than:

> Annotating data on a map using text.

However, I think a better excerpt would be more like:

> Rendering values from attribute tables as text on maps near their feature

This would seem to be in line with the [definition of labeling at wiki.GIS.com](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Labeling_(map_design)):

> Cartographic labeling is the craft of placing text on a map in
>   relation to the map  symbols, together representing features and
>   properties of the real world. Using text effectively creates maps that
>   are clear, informative, and attractive. It is part of typography which
>   is an essential element of cartographic design.

I do not recall ever seeing a question tagged with [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) when I think they meant [classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), or vice versa, but [Labeling Excluded Data of Classification in ArcGIS legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227030) (which is the only question tagged with both) seems to be about the labels placed next to legend patches.  Rather than getting into trying to distinguish feature labelling from legend labelling using a new tag perhaps we can just retag that question from [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) to [legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend).

This might lead to sentences in the tag wiki for [labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labeling) that include:

> Use this tag only for feature labelling questions.  For questions
>   about legend labels use the [legend](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend) tag instead.

Applying that guideline suggests [65 questions that may need review](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blabeling%5D%20legend).

Comment: Are you willing to accept a suggestion to write the [tag:labeling] tag excerpt as: _"Rendering values from attribute tables as text on maps near their feature. Use this tag only for feature labelling questions. For questions about legend labels use the [legend] tag instead."_? I think guidance about how to use the tag should be in the excerpt (not in the wiki). Also, I suggest adding the GIS.com definition of 'labeling' in the tag wiki? What do you think?

Comment: @AndreSilva That would work for me.

Comment: It is done. Tks.